# Remove all the activites before restarting app.

Tags: java, android

Does someknow how I get set flags at the main (startup) activity? I want that all activties will be removed of the stack.

This is my code know, but it doenst work:

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, Main.class);

mainIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(mainIntent);

setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

LoadData();
```

}

I have also tried to use `android:clearTaskOnLaunch` but that seems not to work...

Comment: why are you calling `setFlags()` in `onCreate()`? In my opinion it should be called when you are starting new activity. Can you tell me more details about what you are trying to do, maybe I can help

Comment: Well this is the splash screen of my app. Before the app starts, I check if there is a internet connection. If there is not a internet connection, a dialog appears, so a users can exit the app. But if the app previously has been opened with internet and the user clicks on the close button (in the dialog for no internet), the previously activity appears :S In the event of the close button I use system.exit(0); I hope you understand what my problem is :)

Answer (score 0):

AndroidManifest.xml update as shown below,

```
<activity
        android:name="Main" android:label="Post an Ad" android:launchMode="singleTop">
```

Use following code,

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,Main.class);
            intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
            startActivity( intent );
```